mysqld_exporter not capturing events_statements_summary_by_digest metrics?
I'm trying to capture metrics like mysql_perf_schema_events_statements_seconds_total, so I tried running mysqld_exporter with multiple flags/collectors, mainly:
--collect.auto_increment.columns
--collect.binlog_size
--collect.global_status
--collect.global_variables
--collect.info_schema.innodb_metrics
--collect.info_schema.processlist
--collect.info_schema.query_response_time
--collect.info_schema.tables
--collect.info_schema.tablestats
--collect.info_schema.userstats
--collect.info_schema.clientstats
--collect.perf_schema.eventsstatements
--collect.perf_schema.eventswaits
--collect.perf_schema.file_events
--collect.mysql.user
--collect.slave_status

And I made sure the performance schema is enabled, the statement-level instrumentation is also enabled, and the required consumers as well. And I have also added this to .my.cnf:
performance_schema = ON
performance_schema_instrument = '%=ON'
performance-schema-instrument='statement/%=ON'
performance-schema-consumer-events-statements-current=ON
performance-schema-consumer-events-statements-history=ON
performance-schema-consumer-events-statements-history-long=ON
performance-schema-consumer-statements-digest=ON

However, the metrics are still not showing, what could be the issue?
MySQL version is 5.7.42 on Ubuntu 18 and the exporter version is 0.16.0

I downgraded to exporter version 0.15.0 and the metrics appeared
